# Stata: Using if with value labels

Tags: if-statement, stata

I faced an issue using *if* with value labels.

```
set obs 5
gen var1 = _n
label define l_var1 1 "cat1" 2 "cat1" 3 "cat2" 4 "cat3" 5 "cat3"
label val var1 l_var1
keep if var1=="cat3":l_var1
(4 observations deleted)
```

I expected 3 records to be deleted. How can I achieve this?

I am using Stata 16.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"cat3":l_var1` does not look up all values in `l_var1` that corresponds to `"cat3"`. It returns the first value that corresponds to the string `"cat3"`.

So `"cat3":l_var1` evaluates to `4` so `keep if var1=="cat3":l_var1` evaluates to `keep if var1==4` and therefore only one observation is kept.

See code below that shows this behavior. This is not the way you seem to want `"cat3":l_var1` to behave, but this is how it behaves.

```
set obs 5
gen var1 = _n
label define l_var1 1 "cat1" 2 "cat1" 3 "cat2"  5 "cat3" 4 "cat3"
label val var1 l_var1
gen var2 = "cat3":l_var1
gen var3 = 1 if var1=="cat3":l_var1
```

This answers what is going on in your code. The code below is a better way to solve what you are trying to do.

```
set obs 5
gen var1 = _n
label define l_var1 1 "cat1" 2 "cat1" 3 "cat2"  5 "cat3" 4 "cat3"
label val var1 l_var1

decode var1, generate(var_str)
keep if var_str == "cat3"
```

Comment: I want to keep all the records with the label `cat3`.

Comment: The clean Stata way would be to only have one value that corresponds to the label `cat3`, is that not possible?

Comment: I have added to my answer above. Is that an answer to your question?

Comment: Sometimes, there is a need of subgrouping a few categories and run a few commands like tab etc. without encoding the values. Your answer seems fine. Thanks.

Comment: please mark as answered if it answered your question